# XSL-FO - how to continue numbers in two list-blocks?

Tags: list, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

Does somebody know how to achieve this with XSL-FO transformation? The question details should be clear from the codes below.

`Input:`

```
<section>
    <title>Section 1</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>item 1.1</para></listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>item 1.2</para>
            <orderedlist>
                <listitem><para>item a</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>item b</para></listitem>
            </orderedlist>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
</section>
<section>
    <title>Section 2</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>item 2.1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>item 2.2</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
</section>
```

`Desired output:`

```
Section 1
1. item 1.1
2. item 1.2
   a. item a
   b. item b

Section 2
3. item 2.1
4. item 2.2
```

`Here is the XSL file for lists:`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <!-- templates for lists - supports numbered and itemized types -->
    <!-- the maximum depth is currently 2 -->
    <xsl:template match="orderedlist">
        <fo:list-block start-indent="0.5cm" space-before="0.2cm"
            provisional-distance-between-starts="0.7cm">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="orderedlist//orderedlist">
        <fo:list-block start-indent="1.2cm" provisional-distance-between-starts="0.7cm"
            padding-top="-0.2cm" padding-bottom="0.2cm">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemizedlist">
        <fo:list-block start-indent="0.5cm" space-before="0.2cm"
            provisional-distance-between-starts="0.7cm">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemizedlist//itemizedlist">
        <fo:list-block start-indent="1.2cm" provisional-distance-between-starts="0.7cm"
            padding-top="-0.2cm" padding-bottom="0.2cm">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="orderedlist/listitem">
        <fo:list-item margin-top="0.1cm">
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:number count="listitem" format="1." />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="orderedlist//orderedlist/listitem">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:number count="listitem" format="a." />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemizedlist/listitem">
        <fo:list-item margin-top="0.1cm">
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>&#8226;</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemizedlist//itemizedlist/listitem">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>&#8226;</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using DocBook? Your input XML looks like it.

Comment: @mzjn No, I'm using just DocBook tags (in case we will use DocBook in the future) but I'm using my own transformation. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you input sample is (added the **sections** topmost element to make the sample well-formed):

```
<sections>
<section>
    <title>Section 1</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>item 1.1</para></listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>item 1.2</para>
            <orderedlist>
                <listitem><para>item a</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>item b</para></listitem>
            </orderedlist>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
</section>
<section>
    <title>Section 2</title>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem><para>item 2.1</para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>item 2.2</para></listitem>
    </orderedlist>
</section>
</sections>
```

at a given **listitem** of first level you can use:

```
count(
    preceding-sibling::listitem 
    | 
    ../../preceding-sibling::section/orderedlist/listitem) 
    + 1
```

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="sections">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title | orderedlist/listitem"/>
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <fo:list-item>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="listitem">
        <fo:list-item>
            <xsl:number 
                value="count(
                preceding-sibling::listitem 
                | 
                ../../preceding-sibling::section/orderedlist/listitem) 
                + 1" format="1.&#x20;"/>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:list-block>
      <fo:list-item>Section 1</fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item>1. </fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item>2. </fo:list-item>
   </fo:list-block>
   <fo:list-block>
      <fo:list-item>Section 2</fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item>3. </fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item>4. </fo:list-item>
   </fo:list-block>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: This nearly works. The problem is that I have another nested `orderedlist` in the first one and the second part counts listitems from the nested list too. I tried to change the level but it made no difference.

Comment: Also if I have another orderedlist below, the numbers continue. I just want to have those two numbered together and the rest from 1.

Comment: Check my answer now. If still far from your intentions, please provide a better description/sample of the wanted output.

Comment: This is great! I tweaked it little bit and it works nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular reason for not using DocBook and the [DocBook-XSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/) stylesheets? That would give you a lot "for free" (perhaps you know that already).

In DocBook, what you ask for is already implemented. There is a `continuation` attribute on [`<orderedlist>`](http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/orderedlist.html) that indicates whether the numbering in a list continues from the preceding list. This is supported in the DocBook-XSL styleheets for FO output (check out fo/lists.xsl and common/common.xsl to see how it's done).